# Android client app not connecting to a server on pc

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio, client-server

I have the following problem... I am writing a system consisting of a Server side - on my pc and a Client side on my lovely Xperia (a.k.a. an Android phone). The problem is that when I attempt to bind my phone to the pc, through the client app, the logcat says:

```
  failed to connect to /*xxx.xxx.x.xxx (port 2002): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

*here goes my ip address, it starts with 192...

Actually I use a try - catch on the client side, within the try I set the socket but the problem is that the process fails, I guess, to create the socket properly as it goes in the catch block... I am running both devices on my home Wi-Fi hotspot. As I said I use sockets, which probably means that the type of my connection is TCP (? :) ). Please suggest some kind of a solution to this because the more I continue reading in forums (here as well), the more I get confused.

A snipped of my code:

```
  public class ClientSide extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

protected String doInBackground(String... params){

    final String SERVER_HOSTNAME = "xxx.xxx.x.xxx";
    final int SERVER_PORT = 2002;
    BufferedReader mSocketReader;
    PrintWriter mSocketWriter;
    final String TAG = ClientSide.class.getSimpleName();
    String data="";
    String outputln = "Me. Android";

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_HOSTNAME, SERVER_PORT);
        mSocketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        mSocketWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        System.out.println("Connected to server " + SERVER_HOSTNAME + ":" + SERVER_PORT);

        //Reads from the socket
        data = mSocketReader.readLine();

        //Writes to the socket, a.k.a. sends info
        mSocketWriter.println(outputln);
        mSocketWriter.flush();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Cannot connect to " + SERVER_HOSTNAME + ":" + SERVER_PORT);
        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }

    return data;
}
```

Thank you in advance, if you need more info I will do my best to provide it. I am an extreme beginner in the Android dev, sorry for my English.

*Update: The server side app is written in java, too build of 6-7 classes, I don't run all that through Apache or any of these. I don't want to just test my app, I want a real connection over the wi-fi, not through the usb.

Comment: Does your Android device also have a cellular connection? If so, it may be trying to connect to your PC through that network.

Comment: `here goes my ip address`. You have one? I think your Android device will have one. And your pc. So where are you talking about? You dont have to obscure such an ip address as its local and millions have the same.

Comment: `it starts with 168...`. It starts with `192.168..`?

Comment: Please show exactly the used ip address if it starts with 192.

Comment: @greenapps the afaik the Socket class requires to get two arguments - on first place the ip of the server to which the client is connecting and on second the port. So, shortly said, that's not the IP of the phone but the one of the computer, where the server indeed is. Celluar connection doesn't help as well.

Comment: How did you determine the ip of the computer?

Comment: @greenapps in cmd I write ipconfig, each computer's ip  (running on windows) can be found this way. It is 192.168.x.xxx just on the right of the IPv4 bla-bla-bla line in cmd

Comment: @greenapps, right, I've misspelled it, it starts with 192., not 168... whatever, ideas? :D

Comment: Switch off the firewall.

Comment: @greenapps, now it's slightly better, it went through the try block but now I get the exception: 
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Comment: @greenapps, ok at a certain point idk how but that error disappeared and I was finally able to send the message (woohooo). Thanks for the help. I have just one last question, do you have an idea what can I do in order to keep my firewall turned on and keep the connection running properly???

Comment: You can tell the firewall to accept connections for your server.

Answer (score 2):

try this: open control panel -> Windows Defender firewall -> allow an app or feature  through Windows defender firewall (on left) -> check on Apache HTTP server and mysqld for private and public networks